# excel shell command launching a bash script fails

Tags: excel, shell, cygwin, git-bash

I have a simple shell script that returns a file.

```
Shell ("c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login '/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/me/bin/sp2 '" & Parm1)
```

This fails as a shell command but works when sent via command line

Is there anyway I can keep the cmd window open when running via the Excel shell command, to see what errors are being encountered.

Thanks

Comment: slowly working through this. I'm findin that Parm1 is not being read either as the Parm or the actual string value. When the parm is hardcoded into the shell script everything is fine. So somehow it appears to have been dropped. Problem now is even with the set debug statement on ( set -x), there is no screen output to see.

Comment: One alternate approach would be to create a batch file that runs cygwin however you wish and executes "PAUSE" command after. It could also output arguments passed to the batch (ie: ECHO %1)